# Why are md5 passwords hashed differently?

Tags: password, openssl, md5

I've been wondering for a while, why does running "echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin" yield different results every time?If I put any of the hashes in my /etc/shadow I can use them as my password and login to my system, how does it work?

```
computer:/ user$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$xlm86SKN$vzF1zs3vfjC9zRVI15zFl1
computer:/ user$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$/0.20NIp$pd4X9xTZ6sF8ExEGqAXb9/
computer:/ user$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$sZ65uxPA$pENwlL.5a.RNVZITN/zNJ1
computer:/ user$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$zBFQ0d3Z$SibkYmuJvbmm8O8cNeGMx1
computer:/ user$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$PfDyDWER$tWaoTYym8zy38P2ElwoBe/
```

I would think that because I use this hash to describe to the system what my password should be, I should get the same results every time. Why don't I?

Comment: If they were the same each time, an attacker could just hash billions of common passwords and easily check for them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They all have a different [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). A unique salt is chosen each time, as salts should never be reused. Using a unique salt for each password makes them resistant to [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks.

Comment: @peter See also: [Why should I hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833) and [Why is using salt more secure?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/) from [security.SE]

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that the output includes the salt after the $1$ (the dollar symbols are separators).

Comment: So in the hash of '$1$xlm86SKN$vzF1zs3vfjC9zRVI15zFl1' xlm86SKN is the salt and vzF1zs3vfjC9zRVI15zFl1 is the hash of salted helloworld?

Comment: @Peter: exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed if you provide the salt to the command line you always get the same result.

```
$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin -salt my-salt
$1$my-salt$S/PsLSioHR8ffN8bpIzsk/
$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin -salt my-salt
$1$my-salt$S/PsLSioHR8ffN8bpIzsk/
$ echo 'helloworld' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin -salt my-salt
$1$my-salt$S/PsLSioHR8ffN8bpIzsk/
```